# Why does the bootRun task of my Spring Boot application not run completely in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I want to use the Automatic Restart and Live Reload capability of the Spring Boot Tools by adding the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools` dependency and the LiveReload extension in Chrome. See this https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3 for more information. However, this does not work because when I run the `bootRun` Gradle task from STS or the command prompt the application is started (and available on http://localhost:8080) however the launch of the task never finishes and never passes the 70% / 80% mark. This prevents the Automatic Restart feature.

My gradle file looks like this. The complete source code of this project can be found in GitHub, see https://github.com/marinusgeuze/metjekindnaarbuiten/tree/master/backend/springboot.

==============================================================

```
buildscript {

    ext { springBootVersion = '1.4.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' }

    repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
       maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }

    dependencies {
       classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
       classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    }
}

group = 'marinusgeuze'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'docker'

jar {
    baseName = 'metjekindnaarbuiten-spring-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
   compile("com.h2database:h2")
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just run the application from STS directly.

Comment: Sometime the answer for a problem is very simple. You are completely right. Just go to Project > Debug As > Spring Boot App and it works. Install the LiveReload plugin in Chrome and it works great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime the answer for a problem is very simple. You are completely right. Just go to Project > Debug As > Spring Boot App and it works. Install the LiveReload plugin in Chrome and it works great. Thanks a lot.